# Plugin conflict with wordpress images

Tags: php, wordpress, conflict

I am working on a plugin e.g. "wp products", in plugin we add products and their images more than one. In plugin the image width height settings registered with new names (Because firstly i think setting names are conflicting).

Now the main issue is i add a new post or page and add images in editor with high resolution e.g. 2000x2000, it save successfully, when i view the post the image is show on the post or page with its high resolution and design get messy. When i deactivate my plugin and see the post or page the image is showed perfectly in content.

I don't get the point where is my plugin conflicting.

Anyone please help me.

Comment: how about some code? sounds like you are hooking into some WP image handler function and messing with it or something.

Comment: Sorry Code is official, i want only hints..... where is the confliction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok

I found the bug in css file, there is a one class name

```
entry-content img{ max-width: inherit !important }
```

I delete this class and my plugin and web work perfect.